# Конфликт между AdminDirectory.Users.get() и Cloud Platform

Tags: google-apps-script

Возникла проблема. Задача такая, нужно в apps script проверить, существует ли почтовый адрес, что бы обработать случай несуществующего почтового адреса. Но возникает вот такая ошибка, как это можно исправить? Изначально всё было хорошо. Если почтового адреса не существует то я попадаю в блок catch, однако после того как я что-то разрешил, модальное окно вылетало, теперь при любом существующем адресе я попадаю в блок catch. Вот код проблемный let check_user; // проверить, существует ли такая почта или нет

```
...() {
  try {
    // Если почта не существует то эта строчка вызовет ошибку и попадём в catch
    check_user = AdminDirectory.Users.get(ENROLLE_EMAIL);
    GmailApp.sendEmail(ENROLLE_EMAIL, String(teme), '', {
      attachments: array_files,
      htmlBody: html_text,
    });
  } catch (ex) {
    Logger.log(ex);
    GmailApp.sendEmail(
      'araikrasoian@gmail.com',
      "Ошибка в скрипте 'Автоответчик' ",
      'Абитуриент [ ' +
        ENROLLE_NAME +
        ' ] телефон [ ' +
        ENROLLE_TEL +
        ' ] указал несуществующий почтовый адрес [ ' +
        ENROLLE_EMAIL +
        ' ] !\n',
      {}
    );
  }
}
```

Вот что у меня в журнале сообщений

> [20-06-04 13:58:22:394 EET] Exception: Сервис "Admin Directory API" недоступен для проекта Cloud Platform, управляемого скриптом приложений Google Apps. Если вы включили этот сервис Google с расширенными возможностями недавно, подождите несколько минут, чтобы настройки вступили в силу, и повторите попытку.

Answer (score 0):

- Перейдите в Google Cloud Console
- Найдите свой проект
- Главное меню сбоку - API - Library
- В поиске найдите Admin SDK
- Включите
- Радуйтесь